# How Can I add comma after "a" Tag in razor page ASP.NET Core 8

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm trying to add comma(,) after "a" tag in foreach like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Product.Categories)
{
    <a href="#" class="product-link product-cat-title">@item.Name</a>
    ,
}
```

but I'm getting error that says "} Expected". What should I do?

I've tested `@string.join(", ", Model.Categories.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray())` but that will return string or text. I want Link!

It's worth mentioning that I don't want to add another tag Like `<span>` or `<a>`. I know they Work. And I'll appreciate if someone could explain why it doesn't work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-8.0#explicit-delimited-transition

> Use this approach to render HTML that isn't surrounded by an HTML tag. Without an HTML or Razor tag, a Razor runtime error occurs

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Product.Categories)
{
    <a href="#" class="product-link product-cat-title">@item.Name</a>
    <text >,</text>
}
```

Comment: I don't want to add another Tag Like `<span>` and `<a>` or something else. I know that will work.

Comment: @AliJebali How about <text>? You could check the doc in the answer.

Comment: I test it and yeah That's fix the problem and read the document. Thanks for your answer. But another question, this `<text>` put " , " in Html, Can you help me to remove those white spaces? I want to have this ","

Comment: @AliJebali It is "<a>" put whitespaces. I tried but with no luck. Still need a tag for comma to keep the format `    <a href="#" style="float:left">@item.Name</a>
    <a style="float:left">,</a>`

Comment: Yes I tested and the Class of it had padding. I removed and everything works fine. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because your syntax is incorrect. The comma is not presented in a valid manner.

You can use the `Html.Raw()` Razor Helper to render the comma.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Product.Categories)
{
    <a href="#" class="product-link product-cat-title">@item.Name</a>
    @Html.Raw(",");
}
```